# sqoop export for hive views

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop hive view to SQL server database however i'm getting "object not found error". Does sqoop export works for hive views?

```
sqoop export --connect 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:<Connection String>' --table 'tax_vw' --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table tax_vw --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username XXX  --password YYY --update-mode allowinsert
```

> INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore. ERROR tool.ExportTool:
> Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException:
> NoSuchObjectException(message:***default.tax_vw table not found***)

Need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do using sqoop export, even if `--hcatalog-table` specified, it works only with tables and if not in HCatalog mode, it supports only exporting from directories, also no queries are supported in `sqoop-export`.

You can load your view data into table:

```
create table tax_table as select * from default.tax_vw;
```

And use `--hcatalog-table tax_table`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to avoid creating a table and use view instead.